# Convert character value to DATE MMDDYYYY

Tags: sas, radix

I have character variable as below

03211962
04181968

when i run this , the excEl output shows like 
3211962
It removes 0. 
I need to change this as DATE MMDDYYYY.

Comment: You need to provide more information. How are you exporting your data, make sure to include your code at a minimum and explain what isn't happening. As phrased this question does not meet SO rules.

Comment: i only want to change character variable '03211962' to date MMDDYYYY

Comment: Yes, but it could be Excel garbling the data and have nothing to do with SAS, typically leading zeroes issue have to do with Excel. Especially if you created a CSV and are viewing it in Excel. A straight date conversion won't solve your problem if this is the case. Which is why you need to provide more information. There is a solution below but it's not the most efficient solution, this can be converted in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the function `mdy`. Here is an example based on what you've provided.

```
data ds;
input dte $;
    datalines;
03211962
04181968
;
run;

data ds;
set ds;
format date MMDDYY10.;
mnth = input(substr(dte,1,2),2.);
day  = input(substr(dte,3,2),2.);
year = input(substr(dte,5,4),4.);
date = mdy(mnth,day,year);
run;
```

In the first data step I read in the two values as the character variable `dte` and then in the second data step I convert the values to their numeric counterparts. The line `mnth = input(substr(dte,1,2),2.);` is just taking the first 2 characters in the `dte` variable and converting it to a numeric variable. The `mdy` function takes numeric values for month, day and year.

I would recommend looking [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001263753.htm) for other ways to format the date.